# Polars DataFrame save to sql

Tags: python-polars, rust-polars

Is there a way to save Polars DataFrame into a database, MS SQL for example?

ConnectorX library doesn’t seem to have that option.

Comment: I don't know of a way, but you can always do `df.to_pandas().to_sql(...)` for now.

Comment: For **`polars>=0.16.10`** you can use `df.write_database()` [method](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/releases/tag/py-0.16.10).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polars doesen't support direct writing to a database. You can proceed in two ways:

1. Export the DataFrame in an intermediate format (such as .csv using .write_csv()), then import it into the database.
2. Process it in memory: you can convert the DataFrame in a simpler data structure using .to_dicts(). The result will be a list of dictionaries, each of them containing a row in key/value format. At this point is easy to insert them into a database using SqlAlchemy or any specific library for your database of choice.

Answer (score 6):

Polars exposes the `write_database` method on the `DataFrame` class.

Answer (score 0):

```
Using polars 0.20.5 `write_database` for sqlite3 always returns an error. On the other hand, `read_database` works well.

Sample code:

    import sqlite3
    import polars as pl
    conn = sqlite3.connect("test.db" )

    #this code works well.
    pl.read_database(
        query='SELECT * FROM table',
        connection = conn ,
    )
    
    #this code makes error 
    df_insertdata.write_database(
        table_name = "table",
        connection = conn,
    ) 

From [the polars web site] 
polars.DataFrame.write_database
https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.DataFrame.write_database.html#polars.DataFrame.write_databasel:
```

Comment: I do not see how this answers the question. Are you sure that you attempt to answer according to [answer]. It seems more like a description of something you want explained or want help with.